# Plotting the solution to an equation with Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a function `f(x,t)` and I'd like to plot the function of the solution `x(t)` of `f(x(t),t)=0` using Mathematica. How can I do it?

Mathematica is often quite different to other programming languages I can use. Normally, I would try something looking like:

```
Create arrays X, T

For t in T do
   solve (numerically) f(x,t)=0, append the solution to X

Plot X
```

However, I don't know really well how to use loops in Mathematica yet, and the same for arrays, so I'm having serious problems doing this.

Is there some rapid, direct way of solving this problem with Mathematica? If not, could somebody please help me out with this?

Also, does anybody have a better title for the question?

---

**Edit:** Following the suggestion of @LutzL, I would try something like the following:

```
Table[FindRoot[f[x,t]==0,{x,x_0}],{t,start,stop,step}]
```

Would this work correctly?

I still have a problem, because my function `f(x,t)` is highly nonlinear, and thus i would like to input a good starting point for every `t`. Specifically, I know the solution for `t=0` and I would like to use for time step `t_{n+1}` the solution for `t_n`. Is there a way to do this?

---

**Edit 2:** I solved the problem the following way:

```
tmax = 10; nsteps = 100*tmax;
thrust = {v/2 - g}; angle = {Pi/2};
For[i = 1, i <= nsteps, i++, 
  sol = {thr, \[Theta]} /. 
    FindRoot[{eq1[i*tmax/nsteps], 
      eq2[i*tmax/nsteps]}, {{thr, Last[thrust]}, {\[Theta], 
       Last[angle]}}]; AppendTo[thrust, sol[[1]]]; 
  AppendTo[angle, sol[[2]]]];
ListPlot[Table[{i*tmax/nsteps, thrust[[i + 1]]}, {i, 0, nsteps}]]
ListPlot[Table[{i*tmax/nsteps, angle[[i + 1]]/Pi}, {i, 0, nsteps}]]
```

where `eq1` and `eq2` are my equations and `thrust` and `angle` are the solutions

Comment: You could just simply plot the level sets of f(x,t) in a contour plot. There are options to control which levels are drawn, so the plot of f(x,t)=0 can be ensured.

Comment: @LutzL The problem here is that `x` is a vector, so it would be really messy to do so. Thanks for the good idea anyway.

Comment: Then I would look into building an array of solution points using the table command and the numerical solvers.

Comment: @LutzL I edited my answer with my attempt to do it using `Table`. I still have a little issue. Do you have any more suggestions?

Comment: This claims to deal with the initial point problem (http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/6710/). I do not have mathematica on the computer to try it out or even find out what method is employed...

Comment: Mathematica is a functional language based on term rewriting, and it's quite different from, say, Python or C.  It is very powerful and once you learn it well, you can do implement things very quickly with very little code.  But first you have to learn how to do things the Mma way instead of forcing other paradigms on it!  Here's an example of what you're asking for: `f[a_?NumericQ] := 
 Module[{x}, x /. FindRoot[Log[a x] == Sin[x], {x, 1}]]; Plot[f[a], {a, 0.1, 10}]`

Comment: Some more comments: `Plot` samples points adaptively (i.e. not at regular intervals) to get a smooth and accurate curve.  It's much better to use `Plot` when you can than to tabulate the values first at regular intervals, and plot them afterwards.  Regarding why I used `?NumericQ`, see [here](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/3820).

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for the thing about `?NumericQ`, but still, I would like to be able to select the starting point depending on the value of the solution at a precedent point. How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do it would be to create a list and then to plot it.

You have `x(0)` and you want `x(t) for t>0`. You can use the expression Szabolcs provides:

```
root(t_NumericQ, x0_):= Module[{z}, z = z /. FindRoot[f[z, t] == 0, {z, x0}]]
```

And then you compute and plot a list.

```
list[tin_, tend_, tstep_, x0_] := Module[{z = x0, t = tin}, lis = {}; 
While[t < tend, z = root[t, z]; lis = Append[lis, {t, z}]; t = t + tstep; ];
ListPlot[lis]]
```

Or you can change the last line for a `x=Interpolation[lis]` and `x[t]` will be an interpolation function for the solution `x(t)`

Moreover you can test whether other solutions for `x(t)` are possible replacing `root[t,z]` for `RandomReal[{x_1,x_2}]` where `x_1`and `x_2` are in the range of the `x` space you want to explore.

Comment: Thanks! I put in my question how I solved the problem, but I must say that my way looks way uglier than yours.

Comment: Ow! I didn't see your last edit. I'll have a look at it now. Another thing that can be interesting is to look for extra solutions..